# can i use isFinishing() from a service?

Tags: android

I want to know if my app closing legitimately or from a crash.   When my app starts it sets an alarm which when triggered starts a service.   I cant work out how to code the isFinishing() from the service .  I tried :-

```
if (!((Activity) getBaseContext()).isFinishing())
```

this compiled ok but when run gave the following error:-

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ContextImpl
```

Is there a way to call from a service?
Ron

Comment: I can't really the link between you 2 first sentences. You app should just not crash. If you can see some parts of your code that may not work, you should use exceptions to catch them.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from a wrong casting : `getBaseContext()` doesn't return an Activity at all but a `ContextImpl`.

But still, I am not sure this will solve your problem. See my comment above.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

isFinishing() is works for Activity not Service. Most probably it is written inside your onPause() method of your activity to find out activity is finishing or (pausing or stopping).

Now if you pass activity context to service it will work. But if your context is not activity context hence the exception.